# ow to get matrix column number based on pre determined value, by row

Tags: r

I am new to coding and am using r 3.4.0 with windows10.  I have a matrix with 64 columns and 17000 rows.  By row, Each column contains a number from 1 to 64 with no duplicates or missing values. I want to search each row for a value of 1 across all columns and return the column name or number that contains the 1.

Here is what I have tried:

```
LargeVector1 <- c(1)
which(apply(matrix, 1, function(x) any(x == LargeVector1)))
```

This returns the row number instead of the column number

I also tried this to try and return the col names:

```
colnames(matrix)[apply(matrix, 1, function(x) any(x == LargeVector1))]
```

This is returning all NA's.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `any` returns a TRUE/FALSE element for each row.  Perhaps you need `apply(matrix, 1, function(x) which(x == LargeVector1))`

Comment: akrun, Thank you very much that is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
res =apply(matrix, 1, function(x) {if(1 %in% x) {
    colnames(matrix)[which(x == 1)]} 
    else return NA}
```

Will give you a vector with each element corresponding to colname, with NA representing rows with no 1 in them